# CSS Height Works in IE When Opened Local, Not Remote

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

have a webpage that has an image in it. in the CSS, i define the height to be 20% (so it's 80% of the client window) and the width to be auto. This works completely in chrome and FF, and also works in IE when i open the page from my computer's harddrive. however, when i upload the file to my server, and load it remotely, IE fails to adjust the width/height completely. the image is the full size regardless of how big the client window is.

why does this happen? how can i fix it? any tips would be greatly appreciated! the site is http://mikeseese.com

Comment: If you check in IE developer tools against your local and web copy, does it show different attributes for the image ? Do other elements that are styled by style.css work correctly ? I'm on my mac so can't test in IE sorry.

Comment: yup all my other elements work properly. they have the same attributes, and if disable the height thing for the local file, it looks exactly like the enabled version of the remote file. it seems as IE is simply not interpreting the remote version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way to test IE right now, but this may be related to this scenario:

Compatibility Mode is forced on intranet/local sites by default (Go to Tools > Compatibility Mode Settings) so you may get a different Browser Mode on each site. Watch the Developer Toolbar (F12) to see if the mode changes.

Comment: I think if you add this meta tag to your page, it'll make the behavior be more consistent: 

<!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame -->
2
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 

Haven't done enough research to determine whether this is bad form or not.  http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/snippets-html5-boilerplate/

Comment: the setting above still gets forced in intranets even with the meta tag.